# Treatment of special characters in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I use the following analyzer:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/sample/' -d '
{
  "settings" : {
  "index": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "default": {
         "type": "custom",
         "tokenizer": "keyword",
         "filter": ["trim", "lowercase"]}
      }
    }
  }
  }
}'
```

Then when I try to insert some documents which contain special characters like % and etc, it converts in to hex.

`1%2fPJJP3JV2C24iDfEu9XpHBaYxXh%2fdHTbmchB35SDznXO2g8Vz4D7GTIvY54iMiX_149c95f02a8`  -> actual value

```
1&#x25;2fPJJP3JV2C24iDfEu9XpHBaYxXh&#x25;2fdHTbmchB35SDznXO2g8Vz4D7GTIvY54iMiX&#x5f;149c95f02a8
```

-> stored value.

Sample:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/sample/strom/1' -d '{
    "user" : "user1",
    "message" : "1%2fPJJP3JV2C24iDfEu9XpHBaYxXh%2fdHTbmchB35SDznXO2g8Vz4D7GTIvY54iMiX_149c95f02a8"
}'
```

The problem started occurring only once the data crossed some million documents. Earlier it used store it as it is.

Now if I try to search using,

```
1%2fPJJP3JV2C24iDfEu9XpHBaYxXh%2fdHTbmchB35SDznXO2g8Vz4D7GTIvY54iMiX_149c95f02a8
```

it is not able to retrieve the document. How do I deal with this? The behavior seems to non-deterministic in converting special character to hex.

I am unable to replicate the same issue on localmachine.

Can someone explain the mistake I am making?

Answer (score 1):

That is *not* how the document is tokenized on my end [with *that* analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html):

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/_analyze?tokenizer=keyword\&filters=trim,lowercase\&pretty -d '1%2fPJJP3JV2C24iDfEu9XpHBaYxXh%2fdHTbmchB35SDznXO2g8Vz4D7GTIvY54iMiX_149c95f02a8'
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "1%2fpjjp3jv2c24idfeu9xphbayxxh%2fdhtbmchb35sdznxo2g8vz4d7gtivy54imix_149c95f02a8",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 80,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  } ]
}
```

Reading the analyzer output above, your example text is converted into a single, lowercase-but-otherwise-identical token given the analyzer shown. Are you sure there is no character filter at play? That's what would do the HTML encoding.

You should be able to run it as:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/sample/_analyze?field=message' -d 'text to analyze'
```

Since it was not reproducing with the analyzer directly, I tried to reproduce this on my end by creating an index to test it:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/indexed-analysis -d '
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards" : 1,
    "number_of_replicas" : 0,
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "default": {
           "type": "custom",
           "tokenizer": "keyword",
           "filter": ["trim", "lowercase"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
  "mappings": {
    "indexed" : {
      "properties": {
        "text" : { "type" : "string" }
      }
    }
  }
}'

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/indexed-analysis/indexed/1 -d '{
  "text" :
    "1%2fPJJP3JV2C24iDfEu9XpHBaYxXh%2fdHTbmchB35SDznXO2g8Vz4D7GTIvY54iMiX_149c95f02a8"
}'

curl -XGET localhost:9200/indexed-analysis/indexed/1?pretty
```

This produced the *correct*, identical result:

```
{
  "_index" : "indexed-analysis",
  "_type" : "indexed",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_version" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source":{
    "text" : "1%2fPJJP3JV2C24iDfEu9XpHBaYxXh%2fdHTbmchB35SDznXO2g8Vz4D7GTIvY54iMiX_149c95f02a8"
  }
}
```

So, I tried `_search`ing for it, and I found it appropriately.

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/indexed-analysis/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": "1%2fPJJP3JV2C24iDfEu9XpHBaYxXh%2fdHTbmchB35SDznXO2g8Vz4D7GTIvY54iMiX_149c95f02a8"
    }
  }
}'
```

Result:

```
{
   "took": 5,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0.30685282,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "indexed-analysis",
            "_type": "indexed",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.30685282,
            "_source": {
               "text": "1%2fPJJP3JV2C24iDfEu9XpHBaYxXh%2fdHTbmchB35SDznXO2g8Vz4D7GTIvY54iMiX_149c95f02a8"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

All of this leads back to three possibilities:

1. Your *search* analyzer is different from your index analyzer. This is almost always going to produce unexpected results.

   Using `default` should force it to be used for both reading and writing, but you can/should verify that is actually being used (as opposed to `default_index` or `default_search`):

   - `curl -XGET /sample/_settings`
   - `curl -XGET /sample/_mapping`

   If you see analyzers being configured in the mapping for the `message` field, then that should probably be a red flag.
2. You have a character filter messing with the indexed string (and it's probably not doing the same thing for your search string, thus pointing back to #1).
3. There is a bug in the version of Elasticsearch that you are using (hopefully not, but you never know). All of the tests above were done against version 1.3.2.